# Redirect - Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have this shell script from which I call Java classes to Load the web page. Now I want to alter the shell script code to call another shell script.

```
-DstrHost=xxx.xxx.xx.com \
-DstrOracleSid=DEV1 \
-DSTR_VAULT_PW_ENC="disabled" \
-DSTR_PARAPI_IP="xxx.xx.xx.com" \
-DSTR_PARAPI_U=`cat ${PGMPATH}/_dsa_user_dev.txt` \
-DSTR_PARAPI_KFILE="${PGMPATH}/_dsa_kfile_dev.txt" \
-DCGI_PGM="${BASE_PGM_NAME}.sh" \
https://wwwxx.aaa.xxxx.com/cgi-bin/redirect_xxx.sh
#xxx.xx.xx.MainCgiProgram
# 2>&1
# 2>/dev/null
#-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/proj/gdms/www/cgi-bin/cacerts" \
```

Previously, whenever I call the .sh file the flow will navigate to MainCgiProgram. Now I want to call another .sh file. I tried calling another .sh file but got "Internal Server Error". Please advise what's wrong in my code.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. But, in general, Internal Server Error occurs when there is some problem with the server that is serving your request, like, if you are requesting on www.xxxxx.yyy something, and it returns internal server error, it is some fault at the server, not on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

just add `./another_shell_script.sh` line to your shell script

note:
I assumed both files(another_shell_script.sh and your shell script) in same folder